# find word in a file and delete to the end of file

Tags: regex, linux, sed

i need to find a expression in a file and delete it and every thing after that to the end of file
for example i have file like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>HELLO WORLD!</p>
    </body>
</html><script>
    HELLO
    I
    AM
    VIRUS
</script>
```

and I want to change it to this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>HELLO WORLD!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

it must solve with sed but I don't know how to match multiple line in sed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
sed '/<script>/{s/<script>.*$//;q;}' infile > outfile
```

You don't need to match multiple lines, just match the one line and exit with `q` to stop printing the remainder.

Comment: You can make this more concise (also more obscure): `'/<script>.*$/{s///;q}'` -- the empty regex in `s///` will re-use the last-matched expression.